# Join 2 text file data based on a column value

Tags: python, file-handling

How to implement a joining of 2 text files using python and output a third file but only adding values present in one file that have corresponding matching value in second file?

**Input File1.txt:**

**GameScore|KeyNumber|Order**

85|2568909|2|

84|2672828|1|

80|2689999|5|

65|2123232|3|

**Input File2.txt:**

**KeyName|RecordNumber**

Andy|2568909|

John|2672828|

Andy|2672828|

Megan|1000021|

**Required Output File3.txt:**

**KeyName|KeyNumber|GameScore|Order**

Andy|2672828|84|1|

Andy|2568909|85|2|

John|2672828|84|1|

Megan|1000021||

Look for a key name and record number in File 2 and match it with KeyNumber in file 1 and copy the corresponding game score and order values.

The files have anywhere from 1 to 500000 records so need to be able to run for a large set.

Edit: I do not have access to any libraries like pandas and not allowed to install any libraries.

Essentially need to run a cmd that will trigger a program that does the reads 2 files, compares and generates the third file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to do this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('Input File1.txt', sep='|')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Input File2.txt', sep='|', header=0, names=['KeyName', 'KeyNumber'])

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='KeyNumber', how='right')
```

See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for fine-tuning.

Comment: I do not have access to any libraries like pandas and not allowed to install any libraries and use just file manipulation.
Essentially need to run a cmd that will trigger a program that does the whole thing and generates the third file.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could look at the source code of pandas' `merge` method (accessible via the documentation I linked to above) to see how it can be done? Or just write it from scratch with nested `for` loops.